# Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

when I launch my app in android 12, it crashed and it give me this error,
my project already have this dependency

```
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
```

I updated

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx:23.0.0'
```

firebase messaging library too

and I used pending intent in my project like this

```
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        applicationContext,
        0,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE or PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT // setting the mutability flag
    )
```

error :

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: OkHttp Dispatcher
Process: com.internal, PID: 11866
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.internal: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
    at android.app.PendingIntent.checkFlags(PendingIntent.java:375)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivityAsUser(PendingIntent.java:458)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:444)
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:408)
    at com.chuckerteam.chucker.internal.support.NotificationHelper$transactionsScreenIntent$2.invoke(NotificationHelper.kt:47)
    at com.chuckerteam.chucker.internal.support.NotificationHelper$transactionsScreenIntent$2.invoke(NotificationHelper.kt:19)
    at kotlin.SynchronizedLazyImpl.getValue(LazyJVM.kt:74)
    at com.chuckerteam.chucker.internal.support.NotificationHelper.getTransactionsScreenIntent(Unknown Source:2)
    at com.chuckerteam.chucker.internal.support.NotificationHelper.show(NotificationHelper.kt:101)
    at com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerCollector.onRequestSent$com_github_ChuckerTeam_Chucker_library(ChuckerCollector.kt:65)
    at com.chuckerteam.chucker.api.ChuckerInterceptor.intercept(ChuckerInterceptor.kt:111)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at com.android.core.helpers.interceptor.HeadersInterceptor.intercept(HeadersInterceptor.kt:41)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at com.android.core.helpers.AuthInterceptor.intercept(AuthInterceptor.kt:39)
    at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.kt:109)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain$okhttp(RealCall.kt:201)
    at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealCall$AsyncCall.run(RealCall.kt:517)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:920)
E/WebEngage: App has crashed
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: com.internal: Targeting S+ (version 31 and above) requires that one of FLAG_IMMUTABLE or FLAG_MUTABLE be specified when creating a PendingIntent.
    Strongly consider using FLAG_IMMUTABLE, only use FLAG_MUTABLE if some functionality depends on the PendingIntent being mutable, e.g. if it needs to be used with inline replies or bubbles.
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete crash log? Does the crash point to your own code or some third-party library code?

Comment: update all your  dependencies

Comment: i updated the question you can see the full crash log, thank you

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I finally found the problem,
I had [chucker library](https://github.com/ChuckerTeam/chucker) and I updated it to the latest version and it fixed

Comment: How does chucker relate to this question !!!! but its right

Comment: check release 3.5.1
https://github.com/ChuckerTeam/chucker/releases

Comment: Because chucker didn't set flag for show notifications in old versions

Comment: I had the same problem. I was using Chuck (https://github.com/jgilfelt/chuck). I removed Chuck and added Chocker to a personal project and it's working now (https://github.com/ChuckerTeam/chucker).